# Sorting the result grid in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to sort the retrieved data in the result grid in MySQL Workbench.

E.g. with the query

```
SELECT * FROM deepmining.prediction  
WHERE (search_id = 39 OR search_id = 41) AND lead = 10 AND lag = 10 ;
```

I get in the result grid, when I sort on the column `scale` and `timeshift` (sorting using  the result grid UI, not modifying the SQL query):

[image]

Shouldn't the first two rows be:

[image]

instead, just as if I had appended `ORDER BY timeshift, scale;` to the SQL query?

Or does sort MySQL Workbench sorting on multiple columns, despite what the UI seems to indicate by the presence of an arrow on the columns scale and timeshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort order depends on the order how you clicked the headers. The first click is used for the primary sort, the second for the sorting within the primary and so on. See the following images:

[image]

Sorted by first clicking on **last_name** then **first_name**.

[image]

Sorted by first clicking on **first_name** then **last_name**.